# Is there such a thing as a half-space or partial space in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, formatting, style

My boss has asked me to use the font **Calibri** for a publication plot. I'm running *Mathematica* 9, which is quite an old version.

In the following example plots using `ListPlot` with `Frame -> True`, `FrameLabel -> {"q (nm-1)", "S(q)"}`, and `BaseStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}`, the spacing between the **S** and **(q)** on the vertical axis appears too small on the first (left-hand) plot, but too large on the second (right-hand) plot.

Is there a way to typeset some sort of partial space in Mathematica, so that I can add a bit of spacing between the **S** and **(q)**?  Or would I have to create separate [`Text`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) graphics objects for **S** and **(q)**, which I think would be a lot of work?

```
myData = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/100}];
Grid[{{
   (* (no space between S and (q) in FrameLabel on vertical axis) *)
   ListPlot[myData, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"q (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(nm\), \(-1\)]\))", 
      "S(q)"}, PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> 500, 
    BaseStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}],
   
   (* (1 space between S and (q) in FrameLabel on vertical axis) *)
   ListPlot[myData, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"q (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(nm\), \(-1\)]\))", 
      "S (q)"}, PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> 500, 
    BaseStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Calibri"}]
   }}]
```

[image: exampleplots]

Comment: A couple of options to try: `FontTracking` is an option for `Style`. Special characters like `\[ThinSpace]`, `\[VeryThinSpace]`, etc.

Comment: I would simply write `FrameLabel -> {q["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(nm\), \(-1\)]\)"], S[q]}` and claim that the spacing is correct. It is what corresponds in LaTeX to "S\mleft(q\mright)", notice that some people use "S\left(q\right)", which is wrong.